# route model binding with more than one parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In route.php, I have this:

```
Route::get('sells/{sells}/{slug}', 'SellsController@show');
```

In RouteServiceProvided.php, I have this binding:

```
$router->bind('sells', function($id, Route $route){
    $action = last(explode('@',$route->getActionName()));
    return ($action == 'edit')? Sell::isActive()->owned()->findOrFail($id) : Sell::isActive()->findOrFail($id);
});
```

As you see, I have nothing to do with {slug}. I want to know how can I pass the slug into the binding closure?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What gets passed to that closure is what it is, as your code isn't calling it, but the framework is. You could try getting the parameter from the route. In the closure you have you can pull the parameter:

```
$route->parameter('slug');
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know I can fetch parameters from $route. Worked.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
 function($id, Route $route) use( $slug ){
     //...........
```

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

see example #3

This lets you pass in additional information at the time you define the closure, ( as opposed to when the closure is executed, with its call arguments )

Comment: Undefined variable: slug

Comment: "I want to know how can I pass the slug into the binding closure?"  Obviously you must know the slug, therefore you can pass it into the closure in place of $slug.  I thought that was fairly obvious.  In other words slug is just a normal variable, it doesn't get magically populated.

Comment: The only other way is to have some code in the closure that will go out and find the slug, whatever that is.  By the way I'm not a laravel  user.  But that is how closures work in PHP.  If you don't have access to the calling arguments ( can change them) then the only two choices to pass info into the closure are the keyword `use` or to go out and get them from inside the closure itself.

Comment: Maybe I should ask How can I read and pass the slug parameter using route model binding in the way I showed. Does it make sense for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need to use "bind", use "get" or "post" instead:

```
$router->get('sells/{sells}/{slug}', function($sell, $slug)
{
    echo 'Sell ID: ' . $sell;
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Slug: ' . $slug;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I need to use bind.